# what is a simple way to obtain a time series from the microphone input under Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, microphone

I need to obtain the data stream from the microphone input and perform some calculations on it. The process must run continuously for weeks at a time. The sample rate needs to be high enough for normal voice, but not necessarily high quality music rates. There will be no UI associated, the program I write must run from a command line.

I have searched for a straight forward example but have been unable to find anything which didn't require working with large and highly adaptable libraries such as ALSA. I am looking for something more straight forward preferably with an example program.
Solutions which require an external sound capture device (that is, not using the microphone input as the source) would be acceptable.